# console.log() renders elements as "D.fn.D.init"

Tags: javascript

I have a strongly ingrained habit of using `console.log()` to pinpoint where an element is on the page. Usually if you had a page like this

```
<html>
    <div>hello Drupal.stackxchange.com This is my first question!</div>
    <div>goodbye</div>
<html>
```

and then you ran a jQuery function like this

```
console.log($('div'));
```

your console would spit out this

```
[▶<div>…</div>, ▶<div>goodbye</div>]
```

which works just as good as the element inspector. Hovering your mouse over one of these will make the actual element on the page be highlighted in yellow with a helpful tooltip. It's one of my favorite ways to work with markup, however the jQuery that comes with Drupal makes it impossible by spitting out the following alternative.

```
[▶D.fn.D.init, ▶D.fn.D.init]
```

which does NOT work with the highlighting feature because it's not the actual element being passed to the console, nor is it very descriptive visually.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered the true answer. The problem is that Drupal 5, and older installs of Drupal 6 and 7 came with jQuery 1.2.6 which is *insanely* out of date and doesn't support that feature.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/rgbk/k839Y/

Seen here, as of this writing, most of the code in 1.2.6 is between 4 and 6 years old. Why has Drupal held on to such an outdated jQuer versions for so long? That's perhaps for another discussion thread. 
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/1.2.6

Anyway, the solution is to install Drupal's [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module which will forceably upgrade jQuery to ... well not really a much newer jQuery, but at least past the 1.3 mark which is as old as jQuery can possibly be and support that feature.

So that closes the book on this question, but it raises another much larger concern. Now I'm worried about all the hundreds of other missing improvements that have happened since before I even knew jQuery was a thing.

---

Edit: Clive's answer about the 100-element limit is still relavant after the jQuery Update.

Comment: Ahh, didn't think to ask what version you were using :/ You might find http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28820/how-do-i-update-jquery-to-the-latest-version-i-can-download/ and http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30184/how-can-i-use-jquery-1-7-without-having-issues-in-the-admin-pages to be of interest

Comment: I didn't think it mattered until now! I've been wondering where the "shelf" was for when jQuery is just too old and when it's just barely new enough. Now I know: 1.2.6 = bad vs 1.3.2 = okay

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of digging around I managed to reproduce this on a couple of dev sites and I think I've narrowed down the problem.

The issue seems to be with the *number* of elements being passed to `console.log`.

This is what the output looks like with 100 `<div>` tags on the page:

[image]

And this is what it looks like with 101 `<div>` tags on the page:

[image]

So it seems either jQuery or `console.log` is imposing some sort of limit on rendering the output. I don't have time to look into it but my hunch would be that `console.log` is responsible for that.

Comment: I can confirm the `D.fn.D.init` behavior when running a `console.log(jQuery("div"));` right from Chrome's debug console on *some* but *not all* of my recent Drupal 7 sites.

Comment: @MPD Interesting. Any chance the sites where `D.fn.D.init` is shown have JS aggregation enabled, and the ones where the 'expected' output is shown haven't?

Comment: @MPD Oh, and maybe using the CDN version of jQuery (the minified one)?

Comment: All my sites use jQUery update w/ local files, and it doesn't seem to matter.  JS aggregation, too, doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: @MPD I'm glad I'm not the only one. Looking forward to a solution! This one drives me absolutely crazy some days.

Comment: @MPD Turns out it's either jQuery or `console.log` that's to 'blame' (although the behaviour seems like it would be by design looking at the numbers)

Comment: Very odd.  Never ever run into it.  It's jQuery.  Swap out w/ a non-minified version and it becomes jQuery.fn.jQuery.init: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261670/what-makes-a-jquery-object-show-up-as-an-array-in-chromes-developer-tools

Comment: whooaaa... that's blowing my mind... in a good way!

Comment: @Clive I see what you're trying to do. I get the `D.fn.D.init` even on a 1-element result like `$('#header')`